# how to add array elements in javascript?

Tags: javascript, parseint

Can I add the elements including NaN after converting them to numbers using parseInt()???

here is my code:

```
var a = parseInt("10");   //returns 10
var b = parseInt("10.00");  //returns 10
var c = parseInt("10.33");   //returns 10
var d = parseInt("34 45 66") ;  //returns 34
var e = parseInt("  ") ;    //returns NaN
var f = parseInt("40 years");  //returns 40
var g = parseInt("He was 40");   //returns NaN

var n = a + b + c + d + e + f + g;
document.write( n);
```

This returns NaN. How can i make it return 104 ?

Comment: This seems to have nothing to do with arrays.

Comment: Write a function to accept an array of [a, b, c, d, e, f, g] as an argument, sum them up together in a for loop and exclude NaN in the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well first, to get as result 104 , this is a simple way to do it, let's define a function that parse the Integer and returns the int value or `0`

```
parseInteger = function (number) { 
    return parseInt(number) || 0;
}
```

so your code will be like this :

```
var a = parseInteger("10");
var b = parseInteger("10.00"); 
var c = parseInteger("10.33");  
var d = parseInteger("34 45 66") ; 
var e = parseInteger("  ") ;    
var f = parseInteger("40 years");  
var g = parseInteger("He was 40"); 

var n = a + b + c + d + e + f + g;
document.write(n);
```

and it still returns `104`

however, to use and array, all you need to do is to use the literal syntax

```
var n = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g];
```

or you can use the push method of an array

```
var myArray = [];
myArray.push(a,b,c,d,e,f,g);
```

then you need to loop around your array to get the result :

```
result = 0;
for (index in myArray) {
   result += myArray[index];
}

// result contains 104
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom parseInt function

```
function tryParseInt(str) {
   var result = parseInt(str);
   if(isNaN(result))
      result = 0;
   return result;
}

var e = tryParseInt("  ") ;    //returns 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the values  and then add.
var n = 0;

```
if(!isNan(a))
  n = n+a;

if(!isNan(b))
  n = n+b;
```

or you can creat a custom method that will validate this isNan.

```
var k = [];
k.push(a);
k.push(b);
k.push(c);
var total = 0;
var l = k.filter(function(n){ if(!isNaN(n)) return n;});
$.each(l,function() {
    total += this;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you care about the total sum, you can check for `NaN` before adding, with this little trick:

```
var n = (a || 0) +
        (b || 0) +
        (c || 0) +
        (d || 0) +
        (e || 0) +    
        (f || 0) +
        (g || 0);

console.log(n);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zmuoLjt5/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var variable = isNaN(parseInt(value)) ? 104 : parseInt(value);
```